# Symmetry arguments and plane sheet of charge

Tags: electrostatics, symmetry, electric-fields, charge, gauss-law

The electric field due to a infinite plane sheet of charge is given by $\sigma/\epsilon_o$. Now could we have deduced by symmetry that the electric field's magnitude won't depend on distance?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/38666/2451